# How to parse XML for elements preceding a certain tag?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I would like to retrieve all the sentences preceding a `xref ref-type = "bibr"`. Using this example below my input would be that:

```
xml = "This could be due to two nonmutually exclusive possibilities: first, the HB3 DNA sequence for these genes may be substantially rearranged or completely deleted relative to the reference strain, 3D7; second, only a few of these genes may be selectively expressed, as has been proposed (<xref rid="pbio-0000005-Deitsch1" ref-type="bibr">Deitsch et al. 2001</xref>). To identify regions of genomic variability between 3D7 and HB3, we performed microarray-based comparative genomic hybridization (CGH) analysis. Array-based CGH has been performed with human cDNA and bacterial artificial chromosome-based microarrays to characterize DNA copy-number changes associated with tumorigenesis (<xref rid="pbio-0000005-Gray1" ref-type="bibr">Gray and Collins 2000</xref>; <xref rid="pbio-0000005-Pollack2" ref-type="bibr">Pollack et al. 2002</xref>)."
```

output:

```
{
Array-based CGH has been performed with human cDNA and bacterial artificial chromosome-based microarrays to characterize DNA copy-number changes associated with tumorigenesis :
(<xref rid="pbio-0000005-Gray1" ref-type="bibr">Gray and Collins 2000</xref>; <xref rid="pbio-0000005-Pollack2" ref-type="bibr">Pollack et al. 2002</xref>)
}
{
This could be due to two nonmutually exclusive possibilities: first, the HB3 DNA sequence for these genes may be substantially rearranged or completely deleted relative to the reference strain, 3D7; second, only a few of these genes may be selectively expressed, as has been proposed :(<xref rid="pbio-0000005-Deitsch1" ref-type="bibr">Deitsch et al. 2001</xref>)
}
```

I tried find

```
soup = bs(XML)

soup.find("xref", attrs={'ref-type': 'bibr'}).previous_element
```

but it only retrieves the first one and `find_all`provides a list of the citations but does not allow me to use the previous_element method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the find_all method of beautifulsoup for the  then do a loop through each tags, like that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = '...' # Your XML input

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'html.parser')

citations = soup.find_all('xref', {'ref-type': 'bibr'})

for citation in citations:
    previous_element = citation.previous_element
    if previous_element:
        sentence = previous_element.strip()
        citation_text = citation.text.strip()
        print(f"{sentence} : ({citation_text})")
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` always only returns the first of the corresponding `find_all` [or `None`], and `find_all` returns a ResultSet [which is a sub-class of list].

So, you need to loop through that ResultSet and get the `.previous_element` of each result with either a `for`-loop or [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension).

---

##### List Comprehension

```py
[x.previous_element for x in soup.find_all("xref", attrs={'ref-type': 'bibr'})]
```

should return the list

> ```py
> [
>     'This could be due to two nonmutually exclusive possibilities: first, the HB3 DNA sequence for these genes may be substantially rearranged or completely deleted relative to the reference strain, 3D7; second, only a few of these genes may be selectively expressed, as has been proposed (',
>     '). To identify regions of genomic variability between 3D7 and HB3, we performed microarray-based comparative genomic hybridization (CGH) analysis. Array-based CGH has been performed with human cDNA and bacterial artificial chromosome-based microarrays to characterize DNA copy-number changes associated with tumorigenesis (',
>     '; '
> ]
> ```

and

```py
''.join([x.previous_element for x in soup.find_all("xref", attrs={'ref-type': 'bibr'})])
```

would join that list into a single string:

> *"This could be due to two nonmutually exclusive possibilities: first, the HB3 DNA sequence for these genes may be substantially rearranged or completely deleted relative to the reference strain, 3D7; second, only a few of these genes may be selectively expressed, as has been proposed (). To identify regions of genomic variability between 3D7 and HB3, we performed microarray-based comparative genomic hybridization (CGH) analysis. Array-based CGH has been performed with human cDNA and bacterial artificial chromosome-based microarrays to characterize DNA copy-number changes associated with tumorigenesis (; "*

---

##### `for` Loop

If you wanted the texts grouped with the relevant `xref`s, you could use something like

```py
cited_texts = [{}]
for section in soup.select(':has(>xref[ref-type="bibr"])'):
    prev_xref = True
    for c in section.contents:
        cTxt = c.strip() if isinstance(c,str) else c.get_text(' ',strip=True)
        if not (c.name=='xref' or cTxt.strip(';().')): continue 
        if c.name=='xref': 
            xref = f"[{c.get('rid', '?rid')}] {cTxt}" # c # cTxt #
            refsList = cited_texts[-1].setdefault('references', tuple())
            cited_texts[-1]['references'] = (*refsList, xref)
            prev_xref = True
            continue
        
        if prev_xref and cited_texts[-1]: cited_texts.append({})
        prev_xref = False
        cited_text = cited_texts[-1].setdefault('text', '')
        cited_texts[-1]['text'] = (cited_text+' '+cTxt).strip().strip(';().').strip()
```

and after that, `cited_texts` should return

> ```py
> [
>   {
>     'text': 'This could be due to two nonmutually exclusive possibilities: first, the HB3 DNA sequence for these genes may be substantially rearranged or completely deleted relative to the reference strain, 3D7; second, only a few of these genes may be selectively expressed, as has been proposed',
>     'references': ('[pbio-0000005-Deitsch1] Deitsch et al. 2001',)
>   },
>   {
>     'text': 'To identify regions of genomic variability between 3D7 and HB3, we performed microarray-based comparative genomic hybridization (CGH) analysis. Array-based CGH has been performed with human cDNA and bacterial artificial chromosome-based microarrays to characterize DNA copy-number changes associated with tumorigenesis',
>     'references': ('[pbio-0000005-Gray1] Gray and Collins 2000', '[pbio-0000005-Pollack2] Pollack et al. 2002')
>   }
> ]
> ```

You could also convert it to a single dictionary with the `text`s as the keys and the `references` as the values :

```py
{c.get('text'):c.get('references') for c in cited_texts}
```

> ```py
> {
>   'This could be due to two nonmutually exclusive possibilities: first, the HB3 DNA sequence for these genes may be substantially rearranged or completely deleted relative to the reference strain, 3D7; second, only a few of these genes may be selectively expressed, as has been proposed': ('[pbio-0000005-Deitsch1] Deitsch et al. 2001',),
>   'To identify regions of genomic variability between 3D7 and HB3, we performed microarray-based comparative genomic hybridization (CGH) analysis. Array-based CGH has been performed with human cDNA and bacterial artificial chromosome-based microarrays to characterize DNA copy-number changes associated with tumorigenesis': ('[pbio-0000005-Gray1] Gray and Collins 2000', '[pbio-0000005-Pollack2] Pollack et al. 2002')
> }
> ```

but I find the list of dictionaries (with `text` and `references` as keys) much more readable.